# IC identification

Tags: components, accelerometer, identification

I think it is an accelerometer. It has connections to STM32F303 analog pins. Can you suggest the part model?

[image]

Comment: It would help to know more about what that device is achieving, if there are pins that go somewhere else. I would expect an accelerometer to talk digitally to the main cpu.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the PCB. From the pictures I only identified several tracks to MCU's analog pins. Updated the photo, please see.

Comment: Is it possible to identify the part by the info on it's body?

Comment: Probably it's date code. So you should find out what is the device.

Comment: *Is it possible to identify the part by the info on it's body?* Not always, the "SMD codes" databases (Google that) are not complete. The manufacturer of the device and the manufacturer using that part will know what part it is of course. But this information is not always shared. It is like: customer orders part, manufacturer says: it will have code DAEA1448, customer says: OK, I'll make a note of that. Only the commonly used components make it in the SMD code books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JACKPOT!!! Apparently it's a high-speed CAN transceiver. [Datasheet here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005284A.pdf). Proof on page 17.

In all honesty, Google is your friend. I just typed in "daea 144", scrolled a bit down after telling Google I spelt it right and wasn't trying to search up a law, and found a datasheet.

Comment: Wow. You are great! I was searching for it on the Internet for a week. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I find it extremely funny that the exact CAN bus IC I just linked was asked about 4 questions earlier.